# Lagrange method $y''-4y'+4y=25\sin(x)+e^{2x}/x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is asked to solve $y''-4y'+4y=\sin(x)$ so that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Then it is asked to determine the geral solution for $y''-4y'+4y=25\sin(x)+e^{2x}/x$, $x>0$.

I have done the first part with the result $(\frac{e^{-2x}\left(2\sin \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)\right)}{5}+c_1)e^{2x}+(c_2+\frac{e^{-2x}\left(\left(10x+3\right)\sin \left(x\right)+\left(5x+4\right)\cos \left(x\right)\right)}{25})xe^{2x}$

Is it right? I am stuck in the derivation.

In the second part, can we solve $y''-4y'+4y={e^{2x}}/{x}$ and then sum $Y_H+25Y_{p_1}+Y_{p_2}$? Is there a more "correct" way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you use Laplace Transforms?

Comment: I think it is not supposed

Comment: for the homogenous equation i have another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we will look for a particular solution of $Ly = y^{\prime \prime} - 4 y^\prime + 4y = {e^{2x} \over x}$ in the form $$y = (A + Bx)e^{2x}\text{ where } A \text{ and } B \text{ to be determined.}$$

$$ y^\prime = 2(A + Bx)e^{2x} + (A^\prime + xB^\prime + B)e^{2x} = [(2A+B) + 2Bx] e^{2x}$$ if we set the constraint $ A^\prime + xB^\prime = 0 ----(01)$

$$y^{\prime \prime} = 2[(2A + B)+2Bx]e^{2x} + [(2A + B)^\prime + x2B^\prime+ 2B]e^{2x} \\
= (4A + 4B + 4Bx)e^{2x}  + (2A^\prime + B^\prime + x2B^\prime)e^{2x} $$

putting all these together $$Ly = (4A + 4B + 4Bx)e^{2x}  + (2A^\prime + B^\prime + x2B^\prime)e^{2x} - 4[(2A+B) + 2Bx] e^{2x} + 4(A + Bx)e^{2x}
\\ = (2A^\prime + B^\prime + x2B^\prime)e^{2x} = {e^{2x} \over x}$$
 if we set the constraint 
$ 2A^\prime + B^\prime +  2xB^\prime = {1 \over x} ----(02) .$

solving (01) and (02), you get $B^\prime = {1 \over x}$ and $A^\prime = -1$

so we can take $B = \ln x$ and $A = -x$  so the only new particular solution you need is $$x\ln(x)e^{2x}$$ so that $$L \left( x\ln(x)e^{2x} \right)= {e^{2x} \over x}   $$

Comment: But this way you are using La Place transformation...cann't it be solved only with the variation constants method??? thanks

Comment: @LDLD, what i did is called variation of constants. $A$ and $B$ would be constants if the right hand side(force) were zero. usually it is much easier when you have distinct roots for the indicial equation. here you have a repeating root $2, 2$ Laplace transformation we would have multiplied bt $e^{sx}$ and integrated from from $0$ to $\infty$ in $x.$ then you have to look up tables of Laplace transforms to invert.